# You don't have permission to access /Apps/WebObjects on this server Apache/2.2.21 (Amazon) Server

Tags: java, webobjects

When I am trying to give input in HTML format like `<html><body>Test</body></html>` within the HTML tags  through `WOText` and `WOTextField` components, I am getting the above mentioned forbidden error

> You don't have permission to access  /Apps/WebObjects on this server  Apache/2.2.21 (Amazon) Server.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us some more information? Is it your application? If it is, can you show us the relevant source? If not, are you saying that *other* input is accepted, just not input containing HTML tags? It looks like you're talking about what happens in deployment—what happens in development?

On the face of it, what you're trying to do and what you're observing seem unrelated: there's no reason you shouldn't be able to input HTML tags via a `WOTextField` or `WOText` component.

Comment: @mohan  In development it's accepting the text with html tags and with out html tags(normal text). but in deployment it's accepting only normal text .And but when giving the text with in the html tags the issue is occurring.Here in deployment case the server is  apache2.2.21(Amazone)

Comment: The issue is in deployment BackOfficeApplication. Here the actual scenario is :while defining messages for sending confirmation mails for customers .here  in WOText/WOTextField component  will give the input as <html><body><b>Test</b></body></html>.but the message shows to the customer "Test" in bold format .This scenario is working fine in local system but it's showing the forbidden error after deploying in server apache2.2.21(Amazon) and application run on live case.